# Ignore Whitespace while counting number of characters in a String

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which will count the number of characters present in an input string and store as key-value in a dictionary.The code is partially working i.e it is also counting the whitespaces present in between 2 words.How do I avoid counting the whitespaces?

```py
#Store Characters of a string in a Dictionary

    def char_dict(string):
        char_dic = {}
        for i in string:
            if i in char_dic:
                char_dic[i]+= 1
            else:
                char_dic[i]= 1
        return char_dic
    
    print(char_dict('My name is Rajib'))
```

Comment: Just use `str.isspace` method to check `i` for spaces. Also, I would suggest use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: This seems to be a matter of recognizing white space in an `if` statement.  Where are you having trouble with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just `continue` if the character is a white space:

```py
def char_dict(string):
    char_dic = {}
    for i in string:
        if ' ' == i:
            continue
        if i in char_dic:
            char_dic[i] += 1
        else:
            char_dic[i]= 1
    return char_dic

print(char_dict('My name is Rajib')) # {'j': 1, 'm': 1, 'M': 1, 'i': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'a': 2, 'y': 1, 'R': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1}
```

A cleaner solution would be:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def countNonSpaceChars(string):
    charDic = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for char in string:
        if char.isspace():
            continue
        charDic[char] += 1
    return dict(charDic)

print(countNonSpaceChars('My name is Rajib')) # {'i': 2, 'a': 2, 'R': 1, 'y': 1, 'M': 1, 'm': 1, 'e': 1, 'n': 1, 'j': 1, 's': 1, 'b': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete space -> `string = string.replace (" ","")`

```
def char_dict(string):
    char_dic = {}
    string=string.replace(" ","")
    for i in string:
        if i in char_dic:
            char_dic[i]+= 1
        else:
            char_dic[i]= 1
    return char_dic

print(char_dict('My name is Rajib'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things for you, there's a library called `collections` that has a `Counter` function that will produce a dictionary of values and their occurrences in a string. Then, I would simply remove the whitespace key from the dictionary if it is present using the `del` keyword.

```
from collections import Counter

def char_dict(string):
    text = 'My name is Rajib'
    c = Counter(text)
    if ' ' in c: del c[' ']

print(char_dict('My name is Rajib'))
```

This method is very readable and doesn't require too much reinventing.